# How to implement slide transition effect in iphone application through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

How to implement slide transition effect in iphone application through jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the little amount of detail you've given:

slideUp and slideDown - http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/ and http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/
or depending on what you're doing animate - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

iOS Safari (both the app, and the version used in the WebView) is a modern browser and will run most JavaScript that a desktop browser would run.

From experience, sliding and animating does work, although due to the limited specs on the iPhone it might not be as smooth as a desktop counterpart would be so you might need to find ways to optimise your particular problem.

Depending on what you're trying to do and your experience level, jQuery mobile might be better suited - http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use "data-transition" attribute to specify the type of slide effect you want to have. There are various types of transitions available such as fade, flip, slideup, slidedown etc.
As in your case, you wanted to have the simple slide transition, you need not to specify any transition explicitly as by default jquery works embeds the slide transition(left-Right).